# Need help creating regex redirects for URLs with query strings attached

Tags: regex, redirect

The issue is when using infusionsoft or another email platform, when a URL is used in an email, it adds a query string to the URL. If that URL is being redirected, it will not redirect properly with the query string attached, sending the user to a 404 page.

I am trying to figure out how to correctly create a regex expression in order to redirect the page and catch that query attached to it in order to redirect properly.

I think I've figured out how to do THAT, but then need to figure out how to exclude a URL that has the same beginning text...

For example:
If the original url is: /page-url/
And needs to redirect to /page-url-free/

So these versions need to redirect:
/page-url
/page-url/
/page-url/?inf_contact_key=474a03f754bb3dadf5415b3b652fc7baa6979sf0112d3fe

But I need the regex expression to NOT catch /page-url-free/ since that would cause an infinite loop.

Any advice would be amazing. Thanks so much

Comment: What is your context: Are you after URL rewriting on your web server or do you apply this on a service or tool?

Comment: It'd be great if you could share the regex you have come up with.

Comment: Here's what I've narrowed it down to:
^/page-url/?(\?.*)?$

I've been testing that out the last couple of days and it seems to be doing the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to replace *page-url* with *page-url-free*, with keeping the query parameters (if provideds) exactly the same, the following regex will work:

```
\/(page-url)(?:\/\?.+)?$
```

The above regex will capture *page-url* which can then be easily replaced with *page-url-free* depending on what you are using.